# packing war with diacritical characters in the project's file names

Tags: java, maven, war, diacritics

I have diacritical characters ("Účetní") in names of some files/folders within MVN project. Project is being packed into WAR by MVN job. Diacritical characters are replaced by question marks in WAR. Any idea how to prevent this? I need some files/folders within a project to be named like this.